# How to correctly display a portion of results per page, not all results. (PHP)

Tags: php, json

I'm using json_decode to decode a long JSON file and I want to display 20 results per page.
Like this;

```
echo ($decodedJson['Workers'][0]['Name'])
echo ($decodedJson['Workers'][1]['Name'])
                  .
                  .
```

The part I'm having a hard time is, after decoding all those JSONs, when I go to Page=2 ($page = $_GET["Page"];) The PHP does json_decode all over again and it costs a lot of time. I know this is an extremely noob question but please help me with this.

How do I just decode for once, construct my object or array just once and use it on every page?

And is there any other way of navigating between pages? I'm using a function to learn the current URL, change the "Page=X" part. and echo a "" with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's the only way to do that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to http's [stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) nature, you will have to decode it upon every request. Unless you persist it somewhere, so that it becomes available to the next request.

Depending on the nature/structure/scope of the data, you can store it in a file, in (one or more) database tables or in the [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) superglobal.

Concerning your second question, you could use `$_SESSION` for that too, or even [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php), so that your script would "remember" the user's page even if they navigate away and back again.

Comment: caching of the heavy operations is a good idea, this (almost) does not break stateless nature)

Comment: Yes, that's the whole concept behind the _persistance_ part I mentioned.

Comment: The second option is what I've done with an Android application. It used tide data presented in a large XML file. I wrote a short program to parse it, load it into a SQLite database and then package that database into my APK. No slow "initializing" after install and quick queries. Getting the data into a database is going to be your best friend.

Comment: Well it depends -- that's why I mentioned three different ways. If the data is relatively small with insignificant structure, a simple `file_put_contents('mycache.tmp',serialize($data))` would be both sufficient _and_ straightforward. On the other hand, if the data has a session lifetime by nature, `$_SESSION` might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Set $_SESSION['data'] = JSON file, then on subsequent pages, refer to your session data and use the page number to determine the sub set of the JSON data you want to display. Assuming 10 results per page, some logic like:

```
$start = (pageNum * 10) - 11;
for($i = $start; $i < $start + 10; $i++) {
// process output
}
```

Comment: I think, something like `array_slice($_SESSION['data']['Workers'], $pageNum*$pageSize, $pageSize)` ($pageNum starts from 0) better for this task

Comment: Yup, a couple ways to skin the cat.. I was chasing the simplest I guess.